# Rotational inertia, angular momentum of the Solar system

Tags: solar-system

Is there Rotational inertia of the Solar system as one entity "disk"? Is this even possible?

1. The angular momentum of a multi-point system in the Solar system - Since the different planets have different mass and orbital periods then does create angular momentum, inertia in the system?
2. How can one planet affect another planet in the system from its individual rotation?
3. Does the solar system exhibit rigid body rotation from the mass distributed over planets?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotational inertia of the Solar system](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40491/rotational-inertia-of-the-solar-system)

Comment: Don't repost a closed question please, even if you think it should not have been closed.

Comment: You have two up votes and four votes to reopen [your previous question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40491/7982)! The problem is that those four votes to reopen are invisible to you at the moment because you have lower reputation points (that's just how Stack Exchange works for some reason). The correct procedure would be to edit that question (which you did) and wait for it to be reopened. It's almost there and only needs one more vote. You can copy text from here and paste i there if you need it, but then delete this copy and stick with the original question *Thanks!*

Comment: Okay great, the original question is now "open for business".